# Not able to import cv2 in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

When I do

```
import cv2
```

I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ImportError: libz-a147dcb0.so.1.2.3: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

How should I avoid this problem? What should I do?

Comment: OpenCV was not installed correctly. What did you use to install it? pip? conda?

Comment: The library being linked is not available; which means when installing there was an issue with dependencies.

Comment: Did you do `pip install` and maybe you needed to do `pip3 install`?

Comment: Changing name from cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to cv2.so helped me. Now it's working.

Comment: Have you tried **pip install opencv-python**?

Comment: yeah but the problem is resolved by changing the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing name from cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so to cv2.so was the answer for this.